# Group similar strings in translation interface?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a couple of menus with same options inside like "Add new order" for different client types. So when I want to translate this only one string "Add new order" drupal 7 offers somewhere around 7 translation possibilities with different contexts. Does exist any possibility to group those string in one?